# ¿Cómo pintar un arreglo en html incrustado desde php?

Tags: php

Hola tengo un arreglo que quiero pintar desde php en un html que se envia por correo, quiero pintar el arreglo con la descripción:

```
foreach ($post['aditional_beefits'] as $key => $value) {
                            
       $benef2.=' 
          <tr>
               <td align="center" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 25px;word-break:break-word;">
                 <div style="font-family:avenirLigth, Roboto Condensed, Roboto, Helvetica;font-size:13px;font-weight:300;line-height:1;text-align:center;color:#01b0ef;"><b><p >Complimentary '.$value['description'].'</p></b></div>
                </td>
               </tr>
               <tr>
                 <td align="left" style="font-size:0px;padding:10px 5px;word-break:break-word;">
                    <div style="font-family:avenirLigth, Roboto Condensed, Roboto, Helvetica;font-size:13px;font-weight:300;line-height:1;text-align:left;color:#000000;">
                      <ul>
                         <li> '.$value['complements'][0].' </li> 
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                </td>
             </tr> ';
                    }
```

el arreglo es asi  quiero pintar la descripcion y su lista:

```
"aditional_beefits" : [
      {
          "description":"honeymoon package",
          "complements":[
              {
                  "0":"cake",
                  "1":"breackfast in bed",
                  "2":"roses in bed upon arrival"
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "description":"Airport transfer",
          "complements":[
              {
                  "1":"Enjoy comfortable transportation from the airport to the resorts, and back, once your vacation ends."
              }
          ]
      }
  ],
```

solo que de esta forma no se pinta la lista, solo se pinta la descripción y la lista no.

Comment: Corta la cadena después de `<ul>`, agrega los complementos con un ciclo y retomas la cadena en `</ul>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema principal es la forma en que está `complements` en tus datos:

```
     "complements":[
        {
           "0":"cake",
           "1":"breackfast in bed",
           "2":"roses in bed upon arrival"
        }
     ]
```

Y también:

```
     "complements":[
        {
           "1":"Enjoy comfortable transportation from the airport to the resorts, and back, once your vacation ends."
        }
     ]
```

... etc ...

Realmente esa forma de estructurar es **poco práctica**, ya que `complements` es un array con un sólo objeto json dentro pero sin poder saber con facilidad **cuántos pares hay en él**.

### (a) Solución ardua

Si no puedes modificar la estructura de los datos, tendrás que recurrir a una solución ardua que consistirá en forzar código para determinar de mala gana cuántos pares habrá en cada `complements`.

Esto se puede hacer con una combinación de `json_decode()` y `json_encode()`.

Veamos un ejemplo completo (me centraré sólo en la lista para simplificar):

#### Código:

```
$str=
'{
   "aditional_beefits":[
      {
         "description":"honeymoon package",
         "complements":[
            {
               "0":"cake",
               "1":"breackfast in bed",
               "2":"roses in bed upon arrival"
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "description":"Airport transfer",
         "complements":[
            {
               "1":"Enjoy comfortable transportation from the airport to the resorts, and back, once your vacation ends."
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}';
$json=json_decode($str);
$html="";
foreach ($json->aditional_beefits as $key => $value) {
    $html.="<p>$value->description<ul>";
    #De mala gana, forzamos la obtención de un array
    $complements=json_decode(json_encode($value->complements))[0];
    foreach ($complements as $item){
        $html.="<li>$item</li>";
    }
    $html.="</ul></p>";
}
echo $html;
```

#### Salida:

```
<p>honeymoon package</p>
<ul>
    <li>cake</li>
    <li>breackfast in bed</li>
    <li>roses in bed upon arrival</li>
</ul>

<p>Airport transfer</p>
<ul>
    <li>Enjoy comfortable transportation from the airport to the resorts, and back, once your vacation ends.</li>
</ul>
```

---

### (b) Solución óptima

Si puedes, modifica la estructura, haciendo que `complements` sea simplemente un array de strings. Si lo piensas bien, en la estructura actual los índices `0, 1, 2` ... lo único que hacen es fastidiar a la hora de obtener los datos. ¿Por qué? Porque debes invocarlos directamente para obtener el valor asociado en el par y no sabes de antemano cuántos índices habrá en cada `complements`.

La estructura correcta para `complements` debería ser esta:

```
     "complements":[
        "cake",
        "breackfast in bed",
        "roses in bed upon arrival"
     ]
```

Y:

```
     "complements":[
        "Enjoy comfortable transportation from the airport to the resorts, and back, once your vacation ends."
     ]
```

... etc ...

Así, la  lectura se haría de una forma natural, sin forzar para determinar cuántos elementos hay en cada nodo. Veamos un ejemplo:

#### Código:

```
$str=
'{
   "aditional_beefits":[
      {
         "description":"honeymoon package",
         "complements":[
            "cake",
            "breackfast in bed",
            "roses in bed upon arrival"
         ]
      },
      {
         "description":"Airport transfer",
         "complements":[
            "Enjoy comfortable transportation from the airport to the resorts, and back, once your vacation ends."
         ]
      }
   ]
}';

$json=json_decode($str);
$html="";
foreach ($json->aditional_beefits as $key => $value) {
    $html.="<p>$value->description<ul>";
    #Observa que no se fuerza nada aquí
    foreach ($value->complements as $item){
        $html.="<li>$item</li>";
    }
    $html.="</ul></p>";
}
echo $html;
```

#### Salida:

Exactamente la misma que antes.

```
<p>honeymoon package</p>
<ul>
    <li>cake</li>
    <li>breackfast in bed</li>
    <li>roses in bed upon arrival</li>
</ul>

<p>Airport transfer</p>
<ul>
    <li>Enjoy comfortable transportation from the airport to the resorts, and back, once your vacation ends.</li>
</ul>
```

---

### Recomendación final

JSON existe para facilitar el trabajo, no para complicarlo. Por eso, cuando estructuras JSON es importante que cada dato corresponda a la realidad que representa. Realmente `complements` debería ser un array de strings, no un array de pares.